# Uninstalling Nix after Node, Db-sync & Postgres Installation

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, nix

I have installed via **Nix** a cardano `node`, `DB-sync` and `Postgres` on a single server. 
My plan is to pass my Postgres data into an Apache Kafka cluster.

My node is synced to tip and DB-sync is on epoch 264.
So far they have taken in total 93 GB of disk space.
I searched for what is taking the most space and I found out that the node & DB-sync are only taking 44 GB, while the Postgres database 15 GB. On the other hand the nix folder alone is taking 29 GB.

My question is, is it possible to uninstall/delete nix to save space or will the whole installation collapse?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can garbage collect nix store with nix-collect-garbage tool. This is useful if you have multiple versions in the nix store to get rid of older ones.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I only have one version of nix installed and used. Can the garbage tool be of any use then?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Nix database is required as long as you are using Nix.

At chain tip, the PostgreSQL database will take over 100G.